# In Intellij plugin sdk, how to hide file templates from "New" menu?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm making an Intellij plugin and I want to create file templates from my own menu, not from the "New" menu. However, java and form files with the .ft extension appear when creating new and when creating a class.

Only files with known extensions are displayed, probably the java extension is the problem. However, would it be possible that the fileTemplate is not what I need?

I want to hide all my template from the user.

`plugin.xml`

```xml
...
    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <!-- I tried a lot of options here, but none of them hid it -->
        <internalFileTemplate name="Prometis Form"/>
        <internalFileTemplate name="Prometis Panel"/>
        <internalFileTemplate name="Prometis VP"/>
    </extensions>
...
```

Comment: I'd recommend you contact IntelliJ platform developers directly as per https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html

Comment: You can use the [IntelliJ Platform Explorer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/intellij-platform-explorer/extensions?extensions=com.intellij.internalFileTemplate) to find out how other plugins use extension points, which can be very helpful.